# Post JSON to Codeigniter controller

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am trying to receive and parse a JSON object sent in a POST request using Codeigniter but I cannot "find" it.

This is my controller code:

```
public function parse () {

  $json = $this->input->post();
  $json = stripslashes($json);
  $json = json_decode($json);

  print_r($json);

}
```

This is my JSON object:

```
{"data":"value"}
```

Answer (score 30):

This is the correct way to do it.

```
$input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
```

Comment: php://input can only be read once, and the CodeIgniter input class will already have read it by this point.

Comment: Just add correct content type to your request header, 'Content-Type: application/json'. As mentioned by Chris, Codeigniter reads input before your method get called.

Comment: Whatever you guys are commenting, they have no relation to the date at which I posted this answer, which was correct at the date I posted.

Answer (score 12):

```
$post = json_decode($this->security->xss_clean($this->input->raw_input_stream));
```

When you use $this->input->raw_input_stream you can read it multiple times and its basically the same as file_get_contents('php://input'). This works on CI3. I don't know if it works on CI2.

Answer (score 9):

Try this code, it will output an array with all your parameters.

```
$this->input->raw_input_stream;

$input_data = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream, true);
```

`$input_data` will return array

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
$json = $this->input->post('data');
$json = stripslashes($json);
$json = json_decode($json);
print_r($json);
```

You need to pass in the key of the data variable you want from the post array as an argument to `post()`

Comment: This works: data={"color":"blue"} but is that ok? Would be cool with a library that could "convert" them so that I could use the Codeigniter validation.

Answer (score 2):

Firze's answer is correct but here is a more elaborated answer. I am not allowed to comment so I am posting it as an answer.

It has to do with CodeIgniter not being able to fetch `JSON`. `jQuery` does some under the hood tricks and transforms your data into `form-data-x`, that's why it works when you don't specify the `content type`, don't encode your object, or other situations.

If you want a pure `JSON` the solution is to use `$this->input->raw_input_stream` to fetch your `JSON` and decode it using `php`'s `json_decode`. Check the full answer and code below:

[Retrieve JSON POST data in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602890/retrieve-json-post-data-in-codeigniter/38656283#38656283)

Answer (score 1):

```
controller:
puplic function exam(){
$obj = file_get_contents('php://input');
$edata = json_decode($obj);
echo $edata->name;
}
Go to post man->type->post
url:http://www.exam.com/exam
formate:json
{
"name":"atm fahim"
}
==>send
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have POST data, using `$this->input->post()` it will always return empty, you should put on the input type name `$this->input->post('name_of_input_text')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're POSTing the data and not doing a GET instead? I ran into this issue earlier today (which is how I found this question) and I was doing a POST but using JSONP which seems to be done with a GET.

CodeIgniter has a function called get_post that will get the data from wherever it happens to be.

```
$this->input->get_post_string('data');
```

I hope this helps you out.

You can do it manually like so if you'd like.

```
function get_post($index = '', $xss_clean = FALSE){
    if ( ! isset($_POST[$index]) )
    {
        return $this->get($index, $xss_clean);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->post($index, $xss_clean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for others looking, this might be helpful:

On the browser side, I create my data packet using code similar to this pattern:

```
    var form_data = { };
    $.each($('#mvt_dialog_form').serializeArray(), function() {
        form_data[this.name] = this.value;
    }); 

   // add the address data to the payload
   var result = { 
        form_data: form_data,
        locations: addressData,
        selected_location:  selectedLocation
    };

   // now wrap it all up with a pretty bow
   // Seriously, the key:value format is required for codeigniter INPUT class to be able to "see"
   var movement = {
       movement_dlg: JSON.stringify(result)
   };
```

I then "post" movement to the server.
In the controller, I then use the following logic:

```
    // Perform XSS filtering
    $postData = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    $result = json_decode($postData['movement_dlg']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add correct content type to your request header

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the standard CI methods.
In index.php, insert a couple of lines:

```
    $json = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
    if(!empty($json)) {
        $_POST = $json;
    }
```

Either implement in the bootstrap. 
RIP Codigniter...(

Answer (score -1):

try

```
json_decode(array($this->input->post()))
```

OR

```
$tmp[] = (array)json_decode($this->input->post());

print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: $this->input->post() array is always empty. I cannot figure out why.