# How to Insert and display record without refreshing web page in codeigniter version?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a code here of inserting and displaying record without refreshing web page using ajax and plain php but I don't know how to set this up using codeigniter. Please help. Here are the codes

**inserting.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
 libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".comment_button").click(function() {

var test = $("#content").val();
var dataString = 'content='+ test;

if(test=='')
{
  alert("Please Enter Some Text");
}
else
{
 $("#flash").show();
 $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">
  <span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "demo_insert.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
   $("#display").after(html);
   document.getElementById('content').value='';
   document.getElementById('content').focus();
   $("#flash").hide();
   }
 });
  } return false;
});
});
</script>
// HTML code
<div>
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<h3>What are you doing?</h3>
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="content" id="content" maxlength="145" >
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" class="comment_button"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

**demo_insert.php
PHP Code display recently inserted record from the database.**

```
<?php
  include('db.php');
  if(isSet($_POST['content']))
  {
   $content=$_POST['content'];
   mysql_query("insert into messages(msg) values ('$content')");
   $sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT msg,msg_id FROM messages order by msg_id  desc");
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);
   }
  ?>
 <b><?php echo $r['msg']; ?></b>
```

Comment: Just write a controller with your demo_insert.php code in it and put your database code in a model. That's it.

Comment: but what about <b><?php echo $r['msg']; ?></b>? would it still be in the controller function?

Comment: Are you familiar with CI ? I mean , are you just learning?

Comment: See my answer, it might put you on the right way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602890/retrieve-json-post-data-in-codeigniter/28604136#28604136

Comment: @Eli: Just output it this way: echo "<b>" . $r["msg"] . "</b>";

Comment: How about echoing this data in a table of a view file? How would I do that @Joerg?

Answer (score 0):

In your **wellcome** controller you can add the following:

```
public function inserting()
{
    $this->load->view('inserting');
}

public function process()
{
    $content=$this->input->post('content'); 
 if($this->db->insert('mytable', array('msg' => $content))){
    echo "<b>{$content}</b>";
 }
```

You should then use inserting.php as your view, in application/views, and the ajax url would be **/process**.

Didn't test it, but this should do the trick. Also, you should check this example http://runnable.com/UXczcazDrMMiAAGl/how-to-do-ajax-in-codeigniter-for-php