# Can't Retrieve Post data from JQuery Ajax request in Code Igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using AJAX to create a filtering mechanism, in my code i get the data from the filter fields and send them to the Controller through the AJAX request, when i receive the data i update the table accordingly.

This is my Ajax Script:

```
var suppliername = "Apple";
jQuery.ajax({            
    type: "POST",           
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Welcome/get",            
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        supplier_name: suppliername,
    },
    success: function(html){
        console.log("yay");
        hot.loadData(html);         
    }        
});
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public function get(){
        $where="";

        $field="supplier_name";
        $value=$this->input->post($field);
        if($value!= null){
            $supplier_name = $value;
            $where = $where.$field.'="'.$value.'"';
            $where = $where." AND ";
        }
        else{
            $where = $where.$field.'='.$field;
            $where = $where." AND ";
        }

        $field="category";
        $value=$this->input->post($field);
        if($value!= null){
            $supplier_name = $value;
            $where = $where.$field.'="'.$value.'"';
            //$where = $where." AND ";
        }
        else{
            $where = $where.$field.'='.$field;
            //$where = $where." AND ";
        }

        echo json_encode($this->inventory_m->get(null,$where));
        die();
    }
```

when i manually edit the values in the controller the filter works perfectly, but when i use $this->input->post($field) it does nothing, i tried to print the get and post arrays and both are empty.

Comment: do you mean it works `$this->input->post('supplier_name');`? remember you did not passed `category` from your ajax. your query is producing wrong when you have value for category.

Comment: manually set category `value=null` and check if it is really working

Comment: no it doesn't, i mean when i set the value of $value manually the filter works

Comment: Did you checked with what I said with my second comment?

Comment: yes, it append the empty query and it works as it should

Comment: how come it works?I see if your category value=null ,whatever your supply_name your $where condition ends with only ' AND'how come it works or you did something else that is not added at your question.

Comment: When the category = null the query will be ****** AND 'category' = 'category' which is always true. so it's as it doesn't exist at all but also it will give me the option to change the value to apply a certain filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not allowed to comment so I am posting it as an answer.

Here is my solution and explanation for the problem. It has to do with CodeIgniter not being able to fetch `JSON`. `jQuery` does some under the hood tricks and transforms your data into `form-data-x`, that's why it works.

The solution is to use `$this->input->raw_input_stream` to fetch your `JSON` and decode it using `php`'s `json_decode`. Check the full answer and code below:

[Retrieve JSON POST data in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602890/retrieve-json-post-data-in-codeigniter/38656283#38656283)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this by doing the ajax inside a button event (as i was passing the arguments manually (var x = "some_argument") for testing) and it worked, i am not sure exactly why did this make a difference but it worked (if anyone knows why i would love to know).