# How to read from json data from jquery using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to use jquery to get courses from the database when i click the level dropdown control.

The Jquery code in my view

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function getcourses()
    {
    var clevel = $('#clevel').val();
    var did = $('#did').val();
    var tday = $('#tday').val();
    var csrf_value = $('input[csrf_test_name]').val();
    var postdata = {
        'clevel': clevel,
        'did': did,
        'day': tday,
        'csrf_value': csrf_value
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8056/timetable/Admin/GetTbCourse/',
        data: postdata,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            $("#tm4_5").val(result.tbcourses['t0405']);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status " + jqXHR.status);
        }
    });
}
```

The controller code

```
public function GetTbCourse() {

    $day = $this->input->post('day');
    $dept = $this->input->post('did');
    $clevel = $this->input->post('clevel');

    $getcourse = $this->MTimetable->ListTime($day, $dept, $clevel);


    $this->data['tbcourses'] = $getcourse;
     json_encode($this->data);

    }
</script>
```

please how do i get the result sent by my controller to put in the text field one of which is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tm2_3" name="tm2_3" />
```

Thanks

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28604136/3778613 and try `var res = $.parseJSON(result); $("#tm4_5").val(res.tbcourses['t0405']);`

Comment: You need to echo the result from the controller: echo json_encode($this -> data);

Comment: do as @Sebastianb said

Comment: I have added : echo json_encode($getcourse); yet the result is blank.