# Send POST request with JSON using Axios and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, axios

I am trying to send data with Axios:

```
axios.post( url,JSON.stringify({'i': '90'}))
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

And get it on the server:

```
var_dump(($this->input->post())); // Returns an array |  $_POST
```

For the above JSON value, I am getting this response:

> array(2) {
>     ["{"i":"90"}"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     [0]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }

Without `JSON.stringify`, the result from `var_dump(($this->input->post()));` or with `$_POST` is empty array.

How to send `POST` request with JSON data with Axios and get it on the server with PHP?

Comment: Not 100% sure if this solution will work for Axios as well, so I'm not flagging it as a duplicate. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602890/retrieve-json-post-data-in-codeigniter/38656283#38656283) might help.

Comment: Thx, let me check.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem , finally found that it was because of XSS Filtering , 
use

```
   $i = $this->input->post("i",false);
```

and in axios use so

```
var formdata=new FormData();
    formdata.append("key",value);

    this.axios.post("http://URL",formdata).then(res=>{})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution, but I think there must be a better way.

JS:

```
axios.post( url,JSON.stringify({'i': '90'}))
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

PHP (CodeIgniter action):

```
    $requestData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    foreach ($requestData as $key => $val){
        $val = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // Remove all HTML tags from string
        $requestData[$key] = $val;
    }
    var_dump($requestData);
```

The response:

> array(1) {
>     ["i"]=>
>     string(2) "90"
>   }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use json_decode:

```
$json_data = json_decode($this->input->post());
var_dump($json_data);

echo $json_data->i;

or

foreach($json_data as $data){
   echo $data->i;
}
```