# What causes this failure to insert data in a MySQL table with AngularJS and Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter-3

I am working on a **blog application** with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **AngularJS v1.7.8**.

The Dashboard of the application is "pure" Codeigniter, with Models, Controllers, and views, while the fronted is made up of JSONs managed and displayed by AngularJS.

I have been unable to add *post comments* from the frontend, via AngularJS.

My AngularJS controller looks like this:

```
 // Post comment
.controller('PostCommentController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 
  function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    const slug = $routeParams.slug;
    $http.get('api/' + slug).then(function(response) {

        let post_id = response.data.post.id

        $scope.newComment = {
            slug: $routeParams.slug,
            post_id: post_id,
            name: $scope.name,
            email: $scope.email,
            comment: $scope.comment
        };

        $scope.createComment = function(){
            console.log($scope.newComment);
            $http.post('api/comments/create/' + post_id, $scope.newComment);
        };

    });
}])
```

My Codeigniter Comments controller (inside the API):

```
class Comments extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function create($post_slug){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        $this->Comments_model->create_comment($post_id);        
    }

}
```

In the **Comments_model** model I have:

```
public function create_comment($post_id) {
    $data = [
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
        'aproved' => 0,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
    return $this->db->insert('comments', $data);
}
```

The line `console.log($scope.newComment);`, inside the `createComment` function returns an object with all the necessary "details":

```
{
   comment: "Test Angular",
   email: "razvan_zamfir80@yahoo.com",
   name: "Razvan Zamfir",
   post_id: "67",
   slug: "who-loves-a-butterfly"
}
```

Yet, I get a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` error for this url: `api/comments/create/67` and the MySQL insert statement looks like this (I acn see it in the browser at the url /api/comments/create/67):

```
INSERT INTO `comments` (`post_id`, `name`, `email`, `comment`, `aproved`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '2019-10-31 22:06:01')
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: If you send that json file, using another tool, like `postman` for example, pointing to the same endpoint, are you able to insert the data or you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify Comments_model::create_comment method:

```
public function create_comment($commentData) {
    $data = [
       'post_id' => $commentData['post_id'],
       'name' => $commentData['name'],
       'email' => $commentData['email'],
       'comment' => $commentData['comment'],
       'aproved' => 0,
       'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];

    return $this->db->insert('comments', $data);
}
```

and call it in controller with $data:

```
public function create($post_slug){
    //also you can use $data = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream, TRUE);
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
    $this->Comments_model->create_comment($data);        
}
```

Comment: Great answer Doru, it worked. Could you explain your code briefly? I want to learn. Thanks!

Comment: $this->input->post() can be used usually only when you submit data with content-type multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded (clasical html form) but now your data are submitted by Angular with content-type application/json. that's why you need to get data from php://input stream and pass it to your model. 
more information you can find here 
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-the-php-input-stream
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596216/post-json-to-codeigniter-controller/15389426